# Get an object attribute

Tags: python

Simple question but since I'm new to python, comming over from php, I get a few errors on it.
I have the following simple class:

```
User(object)
        fullName = "John Doe"

user = User()
```

In PHP I could do the following:

```
$param = 'fullName';
echo $user->$param; // return John Doe
```

How do I do this in python?

Comment: It's unclear if you want to access attributes of your `user` object *dynamically* based on a string, or if you simply do not know how to access attributes at all. Please clarify.

Comment: (Possibly) related: [How to access object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](//stackoverflow.com/q/2612610)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

To access field or method of an object use dot `.`:

```
user = User()
print user.fullName
```

If a name of the field will be defined at run time, use buildin `getattr` function:

```
field_name = "fullName"
print getattr(user, field_name) # prints content of user.fullName
```

Answer (score 17):

Use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) if you have an attribute in string form:

```
>>> class User(object):
       name = 'John'

>>> u = User()
>>> param = 'name'
>>> getattr(u, param)
'John'
```

Otherwise use the dot `.`:

```
>>> class User(object):
       name = 'John'

>>> u = User()
>>> u.name
'John'
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need to fetch an object's property dynamically, use the [getattr()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) function: `getattr(user, "fullName")` - or to elaborate:

```
user = User()
property = "fullName"
name = getattr(user, property)
```

Otherwise just use `user.fullName`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
class User(object):
    fullName = "John Doe"

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.SName = name

    def print_names(self):
        print "Names: full name: '%s', name: '%s'" % (self.fullName, self.SName)

user = User('Test Name')

user.fullName # "John Doe"
user.SName # 'Test Name'
user.print_names() # will print you Names: full name: 'John Doe', name: 'Test Name'
```

E.g any object attributes could be retrieved using istance.

Comment: But the OP has a string.