# python/chatterbot: get_response different behaviour on print and saving in dict

Tags: python, chatbot

Currently I'm having a problem setting up a simple REST service with flask and a chatterbot. You can see the full code [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8647da49958702efbed345650763ef4e).

The goal is, that the service returns a json with a response from the chatbot to a given request.

The problem is, that when I want to save the response from the chatbot in a dict:

```
dialog = {
            "id": 1,
            "usersay": request,
            # chatterbot function to get a response from the bot
            "botsay": chatbot.get_response(request)
        }
```

It will be saved as a [chatterbot special Statement Object](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/conversations.html#chatterbot.conversation.Statement) like which will then look like this:

`"botsay": <Statement text:bot response>`

When I try to jsonify a dict with this object I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'Statement' object to str implicitly
```

I searched online to find a solution but havent found anything helpful. In addition, I'm not experienced with python.
What is absolutely unexplainable for me is, when I use

```
>>> request = "Hi"
>>> print(chatbot.get_response(request))
```

I will get the correct output

```
> Hello
```

I just want to save the plain response in the dict so can I return it as a json to the client.

Could anyone explain the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by simple accessing the "text" attribute of the Statement Object with the . notation [(see heere).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305061/get-an-object-attribute)

```
>>> response = chatterbot.get_response("Hi")
>>> dialog = { ..., "botsay" = response.text, ... }
>>> print dialog
{ ..., "botsay": "Hello", ...}
```