# TypeError: 'Employee' object is not callable

Tags: python, api

I have a class

```
class Employee(BaseModel):
    Emp_ID: int
    Emp_Name: str
    Emp_Qualification: str
```

and below is code for POST request, i am getting error in last return where i was trying to get employee["Emp_id"] value.

```
@app.api_route("/post-details/{postid}", methods=["POST"])        
def post(postid: int , employee : Employee):
        newlist = []
        cursor=conn.cursor()
        getemploy2= "select id from employee3"
        cursor.execute(getemploy2)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        for list in result:
                newlist.extend(list)
        if postid in newlist:
                return "yes it exist"
        return employee(["Emp_ID"])
```

Comment: To get an attribute of an object, use neither `()` nor `[]` nor `""`. Did you mean `return employee.Emp_ID`?

Comment: When accessing an instance's attribute, you have to do it like: `employee.Emp_ID`, not with square brackets nor parentheses. I recommend you to first learn a bit more about OOP with Python :)

Comment: Awesome mkrieger, Thank you

Comment: Duplicate of [Get an object attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305061/get-an-object-attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access an object's attribute with the `.` operator:

```py
return employee.Emp_ID
```